# Android: Espresso Test with Koin matches(isDisplayed()) fails

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, koin

I'm struggling to make UI tests run reliable, I have a MVVM setup with a fragment with a ViewModel which has a UseCase. Depending on the result of the UseCase I show one of four views to the user: loading, error, no results and result view.
The important part of the fragment layout:

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_postbox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/light_grey_06_dark_black"
                app:visibleOrGone="@{postboxViewModel.viewData.hasData}" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/includedNoResults"
                layout="@layout/view_no_results_postbox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:visibleOrGone="@{postboxViewModel.viewData.hasNoResults}" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/includedError"
                layout="@layout/view_error_postbox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:viewModel="@{postboxViewModel}"
                app:visibleOrGone="@{postboxViewModel.viewData.hasError}" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/includedLoading"
                layout="@layout/view_loading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:visibleOrGone="@{postboxViewModel.viewData.isLoading}" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

In my test class I don't call an API, I return only local mocked data from the UseCase.
Test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class PostBoxFragmentTest : KoinTest {

    @MockK(relaxed = true)
    lateinit var loadPostboxUseCase: LoadPostboxUseCase

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        if (GlobalContext().getOrNull() != null) {
            stopKoin()
        }
        startKoin {
            androidContext(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.applicationContext)

            val testKoinViewModule = module {
                viewModel {
                    PostboxViewModel(
                        application = get(),
                        mapper = PostboxItemListMapper(PostboxItemMapper(get())),
                        loadPostboxUseCase = loadPostboxUseCase
                    )
                }
            }
            modules(listOf(testKoinViewModule))
        }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        unmockkAll()
        stopKoin()
    }

    @Test
    fun showLoadingViewTest() {
        // Given
        coEvery {
            loadPostboxUseCase.load()
        } returns flowOf(Resource.loading())

        // When
        launchFragmentInContainer<PostboxFragment>(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme)

        // Then
        onView(withId(R.id.includedLoading)).check(
            matches(isDisplayed())
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun showNoResultsViewTest() {
        // Given
        coEvery {
            loadPostboxUseCase.load()
        } returns flowOf(Resource.success(emptyPostBoxDummyData))

        // When
        launchFragmentInContainer<PostboxFragment>(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme)

        // Then
        onView(withId(R.id.includedNoResults)).check(
            matches(isDisplayed())
        )
    }
    //2 more tests for results and error
```

Problem is now, when I run all 4 tests together randomly one or two of them are failing with:

> androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.
> Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user
> Got: "ConstraintLayout{id=2131362084, res-name=includedLoading, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@b329d0, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}"

If I run the tests separately it works - even the failing ones. My guess, the emulator is too fast (animations are disabled) or the fragment is too slow. I tried it with an IdlingResource like it is described here
[Instrumental Test: Better Espresso without sleep](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/instrumental-test-better-espresso-without-sleep-d3391b19a581) but it didn't help, I got the same behavior.
Since the UI tests are mandatory for the CI pipeline it would be nice, if all of them would run reliable. :)

If you need any more code or information please let me know and many thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like flacking, I recommend you to look at kaspresso framework, since it provides flaky-safety https://github.com/KasperskyLab/Kaspresso

Comment: Thank you Steyrix, I'll give Kaspresso a try and will report :)

Comment: @Steyrix I have tried Kaspresso but it's not stable nor ready for productive usage. 
Issue is still open.